# Write and Read List, Python Pickle

Tags: python, list, tkinter, pickle

I made a program with a List and this List is included in the Combobox. I want to write the List into a file in order to read the List again later, even after a restart of the program.

I tried this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import pickle

# window
win = tk.Tk()
win.title("menu")

List = []
newList = []

with open('data.txt', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(List, f)

with open('data.txt', 'rb') as f:
    newList = pickle.load(f)

# button click event
def clickMe():
    List.append(name.get())
    numberChosen.configure(values=List)

# text box entry
ttk.Label(win, text="Eingabe:").grid(column=0, row=0)
name = tk.StringVar()
nameEntered = ttk.Entry(win, width=12, textvariable=name)
nameEntered.grid(column=0, row=1)   

# button
action = ttk.Button(win, text="Enter", command=clickMe)
action.grid(column=2, row=1)

# drop down menu
ttk.Label(win, text="Auswahl:").grid(column=1, row=0)
number = tk.StringVar()
numberChosen = ttk.Combobox(win, width=12)
numberChosen['values'] = [List]
numberChosen.grid(column=1, row=1)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is your aim with saving an empty list to an empty file, and then reading it back?

Comment: The list is gets filled when you enter something in the entry box.

Comment: Yes but your code at the start saves an empty list to the file and then re-reads it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to save the list to the file after mainloop, and load it at the start of the program.

```
with open('data.txt', 'rb') as file:
    data = pickle.load(file)

...
win.mainloop()

with open('data.txt', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(data, file)
```

This will load the list at the start, and save it after the tk window closes.